# SVN changes view (tree)

Tags: svn, netbeans, netbeans-7

Is it possible to display subversion changes in project or files view (tree view, not a table displayed in http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/subversion.html)? 
So, basicly when i click "incoming changes" all files that has been modified remotly will apear in my project view when other (not modified) will be hidden. Eclipse has such view/perspective (Team synchronize)

Answer (score 3):

I only know this view:

- right click on a project in the project view
- subversion
- Show changes

Then an subversion view appears, showing imcoming and outgoing changes (which you can filter by buttons). It's not a treeview like in Eclipse. I think it looks more like Tortoise SVN but its similiar in function to Eclipse Synchronize view.